# Let a be an integer greater than or equal to 2. If a | mn, then a | m or a | n. Show that a is a prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I understand that this is part of Euclid's Lemma but how do I prove that a must be prime?

Comment: I presume "prime" in this context means that $a$ cannot be written as a product $a=bc$ with $b,c>1$ (which is what is called "irreducible" in algebra). If that's the case, just note that you can take $m=b, n=c$ because $a\mid a=bc$ but $a\not\mid b$ and $a\not\mid c$.

Comment: By showing that if it is not a prime that you can construct a counter example.  That is, you can find $m,n$ such that $a|mn$ but $a$ does not divide either $m$ or $n$.  The prime factorization theorem is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, $a=u\cdot v$ with integers $u,v>1$. Then, $a\mid uv$ , but $a\nmid u$ and $a\nmid v$